# Why is the constructor/destructor called once?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, destructor

Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Copy {
public:

    Copy() {
        cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
    };

    Copy(const Copy& copy) {
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
    }

    Copy& operator=(Copy copy) {
        cout << "Copy-Assign constructor called" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Copy(Copy &&copy) noexcept {
        cout << "Move constructor called" << endl;
    }

    Copy& operator=(Copy &&copy) noexcept {
        cout << "Move-Assign constructor called" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Copy() {
        cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
    }
};

Copy TestCopy() {
    Copy cop;
    return cop;
}

vector<Copy> TestCopyVector() {
    vector<Copy> copyVector = vector<Copy>{Copy()};
    return copyVector;
}

int main()
{
    Copy cop = TestCopy();
    //TestCopy();
    //vector<Copy> copyVector = TestCopyVector();

    return 0;
}
```

In My understanding the line

```
Copy cop = TestCopy();
```

Should call Copy's move-assignment. While the output is like bellow:

```
$ ./test 
Constructor called
Destructor called
```

Could you anybody help explain this? Thanks.

Comment: `Copy cop = TestCopy();` will never call move assignment anyway - there's no assignment in this line. In the absence of elision it would call the move constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [RVO (Return value optimization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and it's a well know optimization the compiler is allowed to make in similar situations.